# MySQL import - Can I have INSERT OR UPDATE together

Tags: mysql, import, export

If I do a SQL dump, I only get one option to choose insert, update, or replace for the queries. Can I have it INSERT if not exists otherwise UPDATE?

Probably an easy answer, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: What sort of database dump are you trying to construct? It's not normal for it to have to be applied against a database with data in it.

Comment: Would the `replace` option work for you?

Comment: Is Replace a combination of Insert and Update? Some data would be new.

Maybe my workflow is off, but I have dev sites off of one database and live site off another. Trying to find the best way to update the live site with minimal disruption.

Comment: REPLACE behaves like this: If a row exists in the destination table that matches the row data in the REPLACE statement (based on PK or UNIQUE KEY value), that data in that row is deleted and replaced with the data in the source (dump file) row. If there is no such match, the source row is inserted into the destination table.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the clarity. I tried REPLACE in the past and ran into some errors so wasn't sure if I was using it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `REPLACE` will work for you (`replace` mysqldump option), since it behaves like this: If a row exists in the destination table that matches the row data in the `REPLACE` statement (based on `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY` value(s)), that data in that row is deleted and replaced with the data in the source (dump file) row. If there is no such match, the source row is inserted into the destination table.